# Installing Windows 7 Drivers

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, thinkpad

So I am installing Windows 7 (ultimate) on a Lenovo Thinpad SL410 via a bootable CD, and the windows installation was kind enough to let me know I need to install a driver. However, it fails to mention what kind of driver it needs, it literally just says, "Select the driver to be installed."

I don't have any of the installation media that came with the laptop.

**My Question:** Where are the correct drivers for this laptop to install windows?

I have googled quite a bit, and found that it might be the HDD drivers. However when I tried them ([here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-sl-series-laptops/thinkpad-sl410) look under 'storage') it didn't work.

**Edit:**
This computer does not have a working OS on it.

Also, perhaps I am doing something wrong when supplying the drivers? I am installing the drivers to a USB Drive (from another computer) and then using the 'browse' button to navigate to and select them.

Comment: Since this is a Lenovo Product, you should be able to use the Lenovo Thinkvantage Update 5. This will show you all drivers that are available for your laptop and allow you to install them in a single click. This should pickup the last of the drivers you need to install

Comment: The computer does not have a working OS

Comment: Windows 7 has the required SATA drivers built in, what mode is your SATa controller in?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know, how can I check?

Comment: @Ramhound it was in ACHI mode but I switched it to "compatibility" and still no luck.

Comment: @Vembu is right with his answer, you need to go to website http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads and find the driver software for your model laptop

Comment: Try http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products?tabName=Downloads

Comment: That's the correct link, but if click on the link in the question, you find that I have already supplied the link to the specific page for the laptop model. The problem is "which is the correct driver"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling a lot, and browsing forums, one post said to check your copy of the windows ISO. Sure enough, the MD5 sums of my ISO and the official ISO didn't match.

So after re-downloading the ISO (and checking the sums), and then burning a new installation disk, (which was verified) there was no prompt for drivers and the installation was successful.